# Are there injective groups?

Tags: group-theory

One exercise in Robinson's *A Course in the Theory of Groups* is to prove that the groups which have the projective property are necessarily free. I'm not able to prove that because I haven't gotten to that chapter yet, but I tried to find in the book any mention of groups that have the injective property. I know that the injective *abelian* groups are exactly the divisible groups. But nothing is said about injectivity in the class of all groups. Why is that?

Comment: The non-existence of non-trivial injective groups appeared today on MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/100245/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

"The only injective object in the category of groups is the trivial group," is the statement of the theorem in M. Nogin's ["A short proof of Eilenberg and Moore's theorem,"](http://mail.csufresno.edu/~mnogin/short-proof-published.pdf) 2007.  The cited work of S. Eilenberg and J.C. Moore is "Foundations of relative homological algebra," 1965.

Comment: Or, as Mac Lane put it, "every fascist group consists only of the identity element." [1950, _Duality for Groups_].

Comment: Was that paper actually published? It basically follows exactly a hint to an exercise in D.L. Johnson's "Topics in the Theory of Group Presentations", published over 30 years ago! And the exercise is in the first 10 pages of the book!

Comment: That's true: http://tinyurl.com/7rpvjrc (link to the Google Books) -- exercise 7.

Answer (score 4):

Another approach is to consider again the free group $F$ on two letters $x,y$ and the automorphism $x\leftrightarrow y$ that gives a semidirect product $F\rtimes C_2$ where the generator $\sigma $ of $C_2$ acts by $\sigma x\sigma =y$ and $\sigma y\sigma =x$. Then consider the canonical injection $\iota : F\to F\rtimes C_2$ and given $g\in G$, where $G$ is injective, the morphism $F\to G$ with $x\to 1 $ and $y\to g$. An extension $\psi: F\rtimes C_2\to G$ gives that $\psi z g\psi z=1$ so that $g=1$ since $(\psi z)^2=1$.