# Extending homomorphism on subgroup to the whole group

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-homomorphism

I was working on homomorphisms and related concepts and I was wondering whether there exist some good criteria involving $H$ and $G_{1}$ which guarantees that *all* homomorphism $\phi$ on the subgroup $H$ of $G_{1}$ into an arbitrary group $G_{2}$ can be extended to a homomorphism $\bar{\phi}$ from all of $G_{1}$ to $G_{2}$.

And just to be clear: When I speak of an extension, I mean that I require that $\bar{\phi}$ restricted to H reduces to $\phi$.

​
My current conjecture is that this is possible for all homomorphism on $H$ if and only if there exists a normal subgroup $N$ of $G_{1}$ such that $H$ is isomorphic to $G_{1}/N$

The criteria is certainly sufficient since then $G_{1}$ is the semidirect product of H and N and by mapping all elements in N to the identity in $G_{2}$ a homomorphism is constructed.
I've not been able to produce a proof that it is necessary also. Any ideas or arguments in favour or against the conjecture?

Edit: As stated in the answer below my criteria for it being a semidirect product is actually wrong. You need the canoncial projection h $\mapsto$ [h] to be an isomorphism. It then guarantees trivial intersection and G = NH

Comment: If $g\in G_1\setminus H$, then set $\bar\phi(g)=e$.

Comment: This is the first thing I thought of but sadly it doesn't really work that way. Some products from outside H may map into H and outside of its kernel. Subgroups are sort of "semipermeable"

Comment: @Shaun, Not sure if that works. Surely you can have two elements in $G_1\setminus H$ that compose to something in $G_1$?

Comment: Nevermind. Sorry.

Comment: It is not necessary.  For example, $G_2=G_1$ and every subgroup $H$ with $\operatorname{id}\colon H\to H\subset G_2$ extends to $G_1$.

Comment: I think you need to be clearer with your conjecture. Do you mean, "every morphism can be extended" if and only if the condition holds? As written it is not true, since for example if $G_2$ is a divisible abelian group, then any morphism $H\to G_2$ can be extended to $G$ (through $G^{\rm ab}$).

Comment: Are you looking for a criterion on $H$ and $G_1$ such that *all* $\phi$ with domain $H$ can be extended to $G_1$? I.e., characterize all $(H,G_1)$ such that the restriction $\operatorname{Hom}(G_1,\cdot)\to \operatorname{Hom}(H,\cdot)$ is always onto?

Comment: In commutative algebra we have injective modules, which are the modules such that $X\rightarrow 0$ has the right lifting property against monomorphisms. This notion should adapt to the setting of groups giving other sufficient conditions (on $G_2$!) for your extension problem. This is of cause a tautology then, but maybe injective objects in groups are well studied and have different interesting characterizations?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Yes exactly! I'm sorry that was unclear in the question, thanks.

Comment: @PrudiiArca: For abelian groups, injective modules are the divisible abelian groups. For the category of all groups, though, [only the trivial group is injective](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/102820/are-there-injective-groups).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I did not know about the nonabelian part. Thanks!

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Patience please...

Comment: I think the confusion wasn't on the meaning of "extension", but rather on where you are quantifying: you mean: for every group $G_2$ and every morphism $\phi\colon H\to G_2$, there exists a morphism $\overline{\phi}\colon G_1\to G_2$ such that $\overline{\phi}|_{H} = \phi$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Yes that's not the only thing I changed but I guess I still need to be more precise.

Comment: Tangentially related: [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/251073/extension-of-a-group-homomorphism).

Comment: Note: actually, as stated your conjecture does not hold; you need $NH=G$ and $N\cap H=\{e\}$. If all you have is that $G/N$ is isomorphic to $H$, you may not be able to do your construction; what if $H$ intersects $N$ nontrivially? Then the map you are defining need not extend $\phi$.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your conjecture is *almost* true. But you need more than just $G/N$ isomorphic to $H$. See below the line.

Explicitly:

> The group $G_1$ and subgroup $H$ satisfy the stated property if and only if there exists a normal subgroup $N$ of $G_1$ such that $G_1=NH$ and $N\cap H=\{e\}$. That is, $H$ must be a retract of $G_1$ (h/t to [Moishe Kohan](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/84907/moishe-kohan)).

Sufficiency follows as you indicate.

For necessity, as usual with this kind of statements, the key is to pick a particular (clever?) choice of $G_2$ and $\phi$ to force the desired conclusion.

Suppose $H$ and $G_1$, with $H\leq G_1$, has the property that for every group $G_2$ and every morphism $\phi\colon H\to G_2$ there exists a morphism $\psi\colon G_1\to G_2$ such that $\psi|_{H} = \phi$.

Take $G_2=H$, and $\phi=\mathrm{id}_H$. Then there exists $\psi\colon G_1\to H$ such that $\psi|_{H}=\mathrm{id}_H$. In particular, if we compose $\iota\colon H\hookrightarrow G_1$ with $\psi$, we get $\psi\circ\iota\colon H\to H$ and $\psi\circ\iota(h) = \psi(h) = h$ for all $h\in H$. That is, $\psi$ splits the embedding $\iota\colon H\hookrightarrow G_1$.

Let $N=\mathrm{ker}(\psi)$. Then $N\cap H=\{e\}$. Given $g\in G_1$, we have $g(\iota(\psi(g))^{-1}\in N$, since
$$\psi(g)\psi(\iota(\psi(g)))^{-1} = \psi(g)\psi(g)^{-1}=e;$$
thus, $g\in NH$. Hence, $G_1=NH$, $N\triangleleft G_1$, and $N\cap H=\{e\}$. Therefore, $G_1/N\cong H$, as desired.

---

The error in your argument for sufficiency is that you are asserting that $G/N\cong H$ implies that $G$ is an internal semidirect product of $N$ by $H$. This is not true in general.

For example, take $G=Q_8$, the quaternion group of order $8$, and let $H=\{1,-1\}$. Then $G$ contains four different normal subgroups $N$ with $G/N\cong H$, but we know that $G$ is not a semidirect product. You cannot extend the identity map of $H$ to a homomorphism $Q_8\to C_2$; you can *map* $Q_8$ to $C_2$, but it won't extend the identity map of $H$ because $H$ is contained in all the nontrivial normal subgroups of $Q_8$. You cannot decompose $Q_8$ as an internal semidirect product.

So you need more than just $G/N$ *isomorphic* to $H$; you need that projection to split. That is, you need $G$ to be the *internal* semidirect product of $N$ by $H$.

Comment: Incidentally, such a subgroup is called a [retract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retract_(group_theory)).